# problema con el uso de java calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Estoy probando la clase Calendar en java, hice una clase que devuelve la hora y los minutos actuales, cuando pido por primera vez los minutos actuales funciona, pero cuando lo hago la segunda los minutos no cambian, por ejemplo ejecuto el metodo a las 12:35, luego lo ejecuto a las 12:36 y aun asi me sigue devolviendo 35 como minuto actual.

este es el codigo:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class HoraActual
{
  static Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

  public static int getHora(){
     return now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  }

  public static int getMinutos(){
    return now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La clase `Calendar` por lo general solo te guarda la hora y fecha que eran al momento en que el objeto calendario fue creado. Si deseas obtener la hora y fecha actuales en otro momento, puedes usar el método `setTimeInMillis()` de la siguiente manera:

```java
//Crear un nuevo objeto Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//Mostrar la hora actual en pantalla
System.out.println("Hora actual: "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

/* Tiempo después... */
//Actualizar la hora mostrada en el calendario
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//Mostrar la hora actual en pantalla
System.out.println("Hora actual: "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu variable *now* solamente obtiene un valor al principio es por esto que siempre va a tener el mismo valor, tienes que volverle a dar un *Calender.getIntance* a tu variable *now* para que vuelva a tomar el tiempo actual.
Ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class HoraActual
{
  static Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

  public static int getHora(){
     return now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  }

  public static int getMinutos(){
    return now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  }
  public static void refresh(){
    this.now = Calendar.getInstance();
  }

}
```

Una vez llamado el método de *refresh* volverá a tener el la fecha actual.

Comment: O podrías cambiar la implementación de los métodos `getHora` y `getMinutos` para llamar a `Calendar.getInstance()` y así evitar el método `refresh` y de paso remover esa variable estática `Calendar now`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Buena idea.